# I wouldn't work if I wouldn't get paid

Tags: grammar, conditionals, would

I would like to know if I can say, "I wouldn't work, if I wouldn't get paid." My question is can I use would twice in a sentece to express something imaginary or I have to stick to would & were.
Please help me to figure this out.

Comment: "Didn't" is more common in that construction.

Comment: My teacher asked yesterday "would you work, if you weren't paid" I wonder if didn't would sound better instead of weren't in this construction.

Answer (score 3):

- If I didn't get paid, I wouldn't work.
- If I don't get paid, I won't work.

The order of the phrases can also be reversed, as in your example.

The first sentence is a "counterfactual conditional". Wikipedia has an article on [English conditional sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences) that might be helpful.

Comment: Can someone tell if "if I weren't paid is correct?

Comment: I would say yes. Note that the use of *weren't* rather than *wasn't* with first-person singular involves the subjunctive, which seems to be slowly falling out of use in English. In practice some people might use *wasn't*.

Comment: Perhaps, 'I would not work, if I did not get pay.'  So avoid the 'paid' past-tense, and refer to what you are receiving, pay.  But it doesn't sound so good.

Comment: I think it's the same if I get paid or if I get the pay

Answer (score 3):

It is non-standard to use "would/wouldn't" in the "if" clause of a conditional: the usual form is :

> I wouldn't work if I didn't get paid."

Having said that, I have quite often come across forms like "if I wouldn't get paid", so that seems to be normal in some people's speech. My impression is that this is mostly American rather than British. GloWbe - the Global corpus of web-based English - has 522 instances of "If I would", 166 of them US and 83 UK (though I'm not sure of the relative sizes of the corpora).

There is one case where 'would' is standard after 'if': when offering something politely: "If you would like to .. "; "If you would come this way".

Comment: To my ear, *"I wouldn't work if I wouldn't get paid"* is what happens when you take *"I won't work if I won't get paid"* (which I think is a perfectly reasonable sentence) and put it into the conditional. This only works because the second *won't* is farther into the future than the first *won't*; *"I wouldn't walk on a tightrope if I wouldn't have a net"* sounds ungrammatical to me. This may be an AmE/BrE difference (or it may just be idiosyncratic to me).

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

> "I wouldn't work, if wouldn't get paid."

is wrong. Just keep in mind that you can almost never use will or would after if.

You can fix it by replacing wouldn't by another verb in the past tense, for example, didn't.

Also, you also need to use "I" in the second part of the sentence.

Therefore it should be

> "I wouldn't work, if I didn't get paid."

Comment: If I thought you would take my advice, I would say "never say 'never'".

Comment: @PeterShor I fixed it.

Comment: "I will if you will." -- there's nothing obscure or problematic about if+will or if+would.